# how to retrieve present absent and leave record using sql server and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> In Attendance Management system user login and just can mark
>   attendance or apply for leave and record save in database.there is no
>   option for absent.how can i show absent in gridview on the day when he
>   do not mark attendance.in below records adil is absent 6 days but how can i show in asp.net that he was absent 6 days along with date?

```
attId   Name    Attndancestatus     Date      Username
 1      ADIL       presnet          14/10/10
 2      Adil       present         20/10/10
```

Comment: you have to compare it against a list of dates they should have been there.

Comment: Do you have a list of dates to mark attendance?

Comment: @MartaB yes dates of mark attendance are saved in database.

Comment: @BugFinder yes i have to compare but plz do write the query or code bcz i am very new to programming thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 3 tables:

- ListOfDatesToMarkAttendance: Have all avaiable dates to mark attendence
- ListOfUsersToMarkAttendancePerDate: Have all avaiable users to mark attendence, on each date
- Attendance: Regist Attndancestatus (absent rows are missing)

Once we do not know the DB schema, you can do something like that:

```
select  d.date, u.name, 
        Attndancestatus = isnull(s.Attndancestatus,'absent')
--when?
from ListOfDatesToMarkAttendance d
--who?
    join ListOfUsersToMarkAttendancePerDate u on
        [relate columns here]
--Attendance status
    left join Attendance s on
        [relate with ListOfDatesToMarkAttendance and ListOfUsersToMarkAttendancePerDate here]
```